# Get the parametric equations of the Cycloid

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, variational-calculus

How to get the  parametric equations of the [cycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cycloid.html) from the following differential equation?

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];

eullereq = 
EulerEquations[Sqrt[(x'[\[Theta]]^]^2 + y'[\[Theta]]^2)]/
Sqrt[2 g y[\[Theta]]], {x[\[Theta]], y[\[Theta]]}, \[Theta]]
```

[image]

I tried:

```
DSolve[eullereq, {x[\[Theta]], y[\[Theta]]}, \[Theta]]
```

but there is no solution

Comment: [This](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) is instructive.:)